# Populate a dropdown menu out of the comma separated Column in DataTable

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, datatables, tags

I am constructing a DataTable with searching feature similar to this link.

https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

But I want to have a Tag search feature. I have a column named Tag column in my table. Each row of the Tag column includes a comma separated string. The table looks like this:

```
"#" |"Type"| "Tag Column"
1  | Type A |       Tag1, Tag2, Tag3
2  | Type A |       Tag1, Tag2
3  | Type B |       Tag4, Tag5
4  | Type A |       Tag6
```

How can I populate a dropdown menu out of the Tag Column such that each option has only one Tag.

I want it only shows filtered rows; for example if I filter “Column Type” for “Type A”, the dropdown menu must show below tags:

```
Tag1
Tag2
Tag3
Tag6
```

I've tried yadcf (the code below), but when I filter for "Type A", the tag drop down menu still shows all tag 1--6. I would like it removes tags 4 and 5.

Any suggestion?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="jquery.datatables.yadcf.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js"></script>

<style>
.label {
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -moz-border-radius: 1em; /* for mozilla-based browsers */
    -webkit-border-radius: 1em; /* for webkit-based browsers */
    border-radius: 1em; /* theoretically for *all* browsers*/
}

</style>  

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#example').dataTable().yadcf([
        {column_number : 1},
        {column_number : 2,  column_data_type: "html", html_data_type: "text", filter_default_label: "Select tag"}]);
});
</script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
</head>
 <body>
    <div id="container">
      <table id="example">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Tags</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Type A</td>
                <td><span class="label">Tag 1</span><span class="label lightblue">Tag 2</span><span class="label lightblue">Tag 3</span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Type A</td>
                <td><span class="label lightblue">Tag 1</span><span class="label lightblue">Tag 2</span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Type B</td>             
                <td><span class="label lightblue">Tag 4</span><span class="label lightblue">Tag 5</span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>Type A</td>
                <td><span class="label lightblue">Tag 6</span></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: what did you try? add your html and js to question too

Comment: Please see my update.

Comment: @Sadaf : Have you tried my code below? Did it help?

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg: Thank you very much for your reply. I tried your code. But It seems that [...$('.label')] has no content. I tried console.log([...$('.label')]) and it returns [].

Comment: `[...$('.label')]` may result in an empty array if being executed *where* or *when* there's no DOM node having `class="label"` on the page. So, I need to ask how *exactly* you ran my code? Was your entire HTML loaded by the time?

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg: I have three separate files as you wrote for test.css, test.js, and index.html. The Html loads fine. I noticed that I need to run your js code inside the `$(document).ready(function() {   })`. This way I got some results for the `[...$('.label')]` array. However the dropdown menu shows one option which is `${tag}`

Comment: It worked!! thanks.I noticed I had to use ` instead of ' for this part of code: `options+=`<option`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking into account your environment, I would suggest to use jQuery rather than DataTables API.

Following code demonstrates one of the possible solutions:

```js
//assign DataTable to a variable
const dataTable = $('#example').DataTable({
  dom: 't'
})

//grab all unique 'tag' column entries into array
const tags = [...$('.label')].reduce((tags, tag) => {
  tag = $(tag).text();
  if(tags.indexOf(tag) == -1) tags.push(tag);
  return tags;
}, []);

//populate <select> with available tag options
$('#tagSelector').html(tags.reduce((options, tag) => options+=`<option value="${tag}">${tag}</option>`, '<option value="" selected></option>'));

//apply tag search
$('#tagSelector').on('change', function(){
  dataTable.column(2).search($(this).val()).draw();
});
```

```css
.label {
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -moz-border-radius: 1em; /* for mozilla-based browsers */
    -webkit-border-radius: 1em; /* for webkit-based browsers */
    border-radius: 1em; /* theoretically for *all* browsers*/
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
<select id="tagSelector"></select>
<table id="example">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>#</th>
   <th>Type</th>
   <th>Tags</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>Type A</td>
   <td><span class="label">Tag 1</span><span class="label lightblue">Tag 2</span><span class="label lightblue">Tag 3</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>Type A</td>
   <td><span class="label lightblue">Tag 1</span><span class="label lightblue">Tag 2</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>Type B</td>             
   <td><span class="label lightblue">Tag 4</span><span class="label lightblue">Tag 5</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>4</td>
   <td>Type A</td>
   <td><span class="label lightblue">Tag 6</span></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```